# How to get IHTMLDocument object to load an image?

Tags: html, c++, mshtml

I am using `mshtml.h` and `mshtml.dll` in a Visual Studio C++ based application. I show tooltips using the Microsoft Web Browser control. When I do this, I calculate a width and height using `IHTMLTextContainer::get_scrollHeight()` as to avoid scroll bars. I have an issue where I don't get scroll bars but the height of my window is not correct, leading to clipping of the data I am showing.

This only happens on a scaled desktop. I have found that if I don't replace an image I have at the top of my web page that I am loading and modifying, the size of the window I calculate is fine. I have a placeholder for my image, which is a bitmap that is 32 pixels high. I replace that image using `IHTMLImgElement::put_source()`. The web browser is zoomed calling `Exec()` with `OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM` and the desktop DPI. I also call `IHTMLDocument3::recalc()` with `VARIANT_TRUE`.

For debugging, both before and after the call to put the image source, and after making that call and doing a `recalc()`, I have added a call to `IHtmlElement1::get_scrollHeight()`. Both calls return 32 (my placeholder image height). I am trying to force the web browser to recalculate the document so that it loads the actual image I am showing, so that when I get the entire scroll height, I get back a valid value.  Apparently this image loading only happens when the window/page is rendered.

Does anyone know how I might get my image to load so the size I calculate is correct?

Comment: In lieu of looking for how to get the image to load, I did a hack that is working. I calculate the Desktop DPI and do this: int nImageAdjustment = DPI(32) - 32; Then I add that to the height returned from get_scrollHeight. Life is full of hacks and this may be just one more.